# Cannot perform subtraction between System.DateTime and System.DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, radgridview

In a `radGridView`, I have 3 columns with the type `GridViewDateTimeColumns`. I need to subtract two of these columns to get the days difference in the third column.

```
 radGridView1.Columns["Ritardo"].Expression = "Periodo-Data_Pagam";
```

I get this error regardless of coding the above line or writing the expression in the designer.
The data in the columns "Periodo" and "Data_Pagam" are both from `SQL2012 DB` dateTime type.

> "Cannot perform '-' operation on System.DateTime and System.DateTime

How can I get the difference (days) between the two above date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `DateDiff(Day,StartDate,Enddate)` you can suceed this

Comment: I tried this in the expression editor: DATEDIFFDAY(Periodo, Data_Pagam) . Still same error!

Comment: you are performing this in sql or c#.?

Comment: I am performing this in c#. I tried the above expression in the designer of the grid.

Comment: However thanks. You gave me an idea. I will try to do this in the db creating a column there and display the same in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want day difference by coding then you can use this type of coding also.

```
DateTime sp1 = DateTime.ParseExact(firstdate, "MMddyyyyHHmm", null);
DateTime ss1 = DateTime.ParseExact(lastdate, "MMddyyyyHHmm", null);
double ts = (ss1 - sp1).Days;
```

difference will be `ts`

i am using like this for date diff column, it would be better option by database.. `DATEDIFF(day,firstdate,lastdate) AS DiffDate`

Comment: Thanks, I know how to subtract two date. The problem was in the context of the dataGridView. However, instead of fighting with the designer of the grid, I decided to create a computed column in the DB and display the result from there.

Comment: i am using like this for date diff column, it would be better option.. DATEDIFF(day,firstdate,lastdate) AS DiffDate